# Trying to use batch file in one location and call powershell script elevated

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use the below batch file which finds the CD drive on the machine and want to launch a powershell script from the CD and run within this folder.  Here is the batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, drivetype') do (if [%%j]==[5] pushd %%i)
cd WIN2k8\Non-Supressed\
start powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -WindowStyle Maximized -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\PatchTest.ps1
echo Press Space Bar to continue
pause
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Trying to use batch file in one location and call powershell script elevated**

You can accomplish what you're trying to do with the below syntax from what I tested and confirmed from my side. I incorporated some techniques into your logic with how I've done this sort of thing with other PowerShell and Batch file process solutions as you explain in the past.

I appended the `WIN2k8\Non-Supressed` path after the `%~j` variable so the `FOR /F` loop will use the full path to `SET` a variable (`FPath`) to later use to use that variable as the full path of the PowerShell script that is being executed. There's no need to use the `PUSHD` command per this method.

I also use an explicit `CD /D` to the PowerShell app Windows directory, call PowerShell from there, and then pass it the arguments, commands, switches, etc. from there—with the PowerShell script's full path (i.e. `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%FPath%\PatchTest.ps1'"`).

### Batch Script Example

```
@ECHO ON

SETLOCAL 
FOR /F "SKIP=1 TOKENS=1,2" %%i IN ('"wmic logicaldisk get caption, drivetype"') DO (IF [%%~j]==[5] SET FPath="%%~i\WIN2k8\Non-Supressed")

SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%FPath%\PatchTest.ps1'"

ECHO Press Space Bar to continue 
PAUSE 
ENDLOCAL
```

---

### Further Resources

- [ExecutionPolicy](http://ss64.com/ps/set-executionpolicy.html)
- [CD](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [Set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

Answer (score 1):

Following *commented* `.bat` script should check all CD drives on the machine **and**:

**if** a medium is inserted **and** inserted medium contains expected folder **then** run an **elevated** powershell session, changes location to  this folder and runs specified script from within it:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem set initial values
set "_folder=WIN2k8\Non-Supressed"
set "_folder=content\recipes\cze_CZE"                          my testing value
SET "_fullPath="                                               necessary

FOR /F "SKIP=1 TOKENS=1-5" %%i IN ('
   "wmic logicaldisk get Caption, DriveType, Size, SystemName, VolumeSerialNumber" ') DO (
  rem next test: is CD/DVD? could be omitted using `wmic … Where "DriveType=5" get …`  
  IF [%%~j]==[5] (
    rem next test: medium inserted? 
    IF NOT [%%~m]==[] (
      rem next test: right medium inserted?
      if exist "%%~i\%_folder%\" (
        SET "_fullPath=%%~i\%_folder%"
      )
    )
  )
)
rem set auxiliary values to keep final `PowerShell` line in a reasonable length 
set "_elevate=Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs"
set "_torun=.\PatchTest.ps1"
set "_torun=Get-Childitem 81*;pause"                           my testing value
set "_arguments='Push-Location -literalPath ''"%_fullPath%"'';%_torun%'"

IF defined _fullPath (

  PowerShell %_elevate% -ArgumentList %_arguments%

)

pause
```

Answer (score 1):

This batch will elevate itself (if neccessary) before evaluating the cd drive and then runs the powershell script.

```
@echo off
setlocal
::Check if elevated
net file 1>nul 2>&1 || (powershell -ex ByPass -Command ^
  "Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath '%comspec%' -ArgumentList '/c %~f0 %*'"
  goto :eof
)
:: Put code here that needs elevation
Set "CDPath=\WIN2k8\Non-Supressed\"
Set "Script=PatchTest.ps1"

for /f %%i in (
  'wmic logicaldisk  where "DriveType=5" get caption^, drivetype^|findstr ":"'
) do IF exist "%%i%CDPath%Script%" Set "CDPath=%%i%CDPath%" & Goto :Found

Echo Can't locate CD drive / script
Pause
Goto :Eof

:Found
PushD "%CDPath%"
start powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -WindowStyle Maximized -NoExit -Ex Bypass -File .\PatchTest.ps1

echo Press Space Bar to continue
pause
endlocal
```