# USB drive variables

Tags: windows, usb, batch, environment-variables

I want to create some simple batch files, that require USB drive letter to be automatically detected, with no user action..
Instead of asking user for drive letter I need it to be automatically grabben and used.
The best method for this is using a variable.. yes, USB drive in use should be the only one attached.. I know this limitation, and I need it.

I searched in many forums, I got these answers: 
"%~d0", "%HOSTDRIVE%:", %cd%

The first two variables did not work.
The last one should work if the batch file exists in the root of the drive, which is not my case.

I need a USB drive variable that works anywhere, without the limitation of being launched from the drive itself.

Usage examples:
chkdsk %HOSTDRIVE&: /f
Convert %HOSTDRIVE&: /FS:NTFS

(To be run from a batch file (.bat) or from an .exe that is converted from .bat "I know how to convert it, and I know how to obtain admin privileges, if needed".. just need the variable, thanks for help)

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate. I don`t want to do a "letter grab" command then doing the main command. I want a variable that works on the fly, and that is dedicated for USB storage devices. Some people told me %HOSTDRIVE% but this didn`t work.

Comment: Consider using and testing with a WMIC command from command prompt on Windows such as `wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get deviceid`. If you can figure out how to get that set as a variable with a batch script, then that should suffice for your need. See here https://superuser.com/questions/1169886/trying-to-use-batch-file-in-one-location-and-call-powershell-script-elevated for an answer of my and others you might find helpful with this.