# Changing Execution-Policy in Powershell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

This is weird, I'm not sure if this is a bug or something but here's my toughts

## First method

When I enter Powershell, the normal method is like

```
Press "Start" > type "powershell" > then hit enter
```

And it loads my user session, wich is located in `~/Documents/WindowsPowerShell/profile.ps1`

[image]

## Second Method

It loads another session, that I cant understand at all...

```
Press [Windows key] + [E] > enter to a folder > in the top bar type "powershell"
```

And it loads another configuration, I tough the only administrator was me, is there a root user like unix systems?
[image]

[image]

So here's my question, How to `runas /noprofile /user:myPCname\administrator Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`? because every time I try I can't.

[image]

I want to execute that command because Windows is in a "secure mode" since I activated the developer mode, that only allows to run signed scripts.
I could easily change that in my user by running powershell as administrator, but with the second method I can't, and I want to, because everytime I run [PSTools](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sysinternals/downloads/pstools) it runs the same "second method" that doesn't allow me to do nothing.
Is there a way to change the execution-policy via console?, please help me!

## Update

just use windows terminal

Comment: I'm puzzled why someone would even open an explorer and hack in powershell in order to run it. It's probably a matter similar to CMD having different configuration depending on how it's started. Just type in `whoami` to see which user you're currently using. As for your "runas" question ... well you'd actually have to tell it to run PowerShell with that command.

Comment: dude I tried that, `whoami` just tells me the same name in the 2 consoles

Comment: Put the commands you want to run from command line/batch and then use the format of `Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'C:\Folder\<YourPSScript>'"`.... You can script out the batch file to be created dynamically if you want. See example here: https://superuser.com/questions/1169886/trying-to-use-batch-file-in-one-location-and-call-powershell-script-elevated/1169895#1169895

Comment: Sorry I found the solution, I just needed to use the SYSTEM user, just enabling something in the registry db

Answer (score 1):

Type in `whoami` to see which user you're currently using. You might also shine some light on this by following the advice from [Determine installed PowerShell version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/determine-installed-powershell-version). Have a look at `$PSVersionTable` and the output of `Get-Host` to see whenever they're different. Also you can check `$Profile` to see which profiles are being loaded (See: [Windows PowerShell Profiles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(v=vs.85).aspx) and its comments).

As for your "runas" question, you'd need to tell it actually run PowerShell with that command. So it would be something like `PowerShell -Command {Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass}`. RunAs is meant to run applications not individual commands.

As for changing the execution policy using a console, run PowerShell as Administrator and use the [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy) cmdlet. By default the scope should be machine. Otherwise use the `-Scope` parameter to change it accordingly.

Comment: so I typed `runas /noprofile /user:rammPC\Administrator PowerShell -Command {Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass}` and throw me an error, is it correct? the console says is syntax error, `whoami` tells me the same names in both consoles, so I don't think the name is a problem

Comment: If you read the `runas` help by using the `/?` switch you will find that you have to enclose the program to be executed by quotes.

Comment: error 1326, how to set a root password? is not the same as my user

Comment: Did you try to actively set the scope? What was the result? Your Quesstion mentions PS Tools but those don't really rely on PowerShell. So what are you actually execution that gets you that console?

Answer (score 0):

If you call `Set-ExecutionPolicy` in the interactive console, it will change the associated registry key and needs to be run only once (unless you have a GPO that changes that config in your machine). If it gives an error, maybe it is because it's not elevated or you don't have admin rights, but you could nevertheless run something like `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser` and it would do the trick. 
Alternatively, you could call powershell with ExecutionPolicy parameter, like this: `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass` .

Remember if you are using runas, you must call the command with quotes: `runas /user:USER "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass"` (but you could run `runas /user:USER powershell` and then call `Set-ExecutionPolicy` anyway).